# Dataproc Spark job fails with IO Exception , failing to initial Spark Context when history server trying to access GCS bucket

Tags: java, apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

We have created GCP Dataproc cluster with image ***1.5-debian10.***  Cluster creation is successful.

Spark Version is `2.4.7` and Running on Dataproc Cluster above image.

**Dataproc Cluster Software Config:**

**Cluster properties :**

```
 softwareConfig:
    imageVersion: 1.5.23-debian10
    properties:
      capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent: '0.9'
      capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
      capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.ordering-policy: fair
      core:fs.gs.block.size: '134217728'
      core:fs.gs.metadata.cache.enable: 'false'
      core:hadoop.ssl.enabled.protocols: TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
      dataproc:dataproc.conscrypt.provider.enable: 'false'
      dataproc:job.history.to-gcs.enabled: 'true'
      mapred:mapreduce.jobhistory.done-dir: gs://</bucketName>/mapreduce/mapreduce-job-history/done
      mapred:mapreduce.jobhistory.intermediate-done-dir: gs://<bucketName>/mapreduce-job-history/intermediate-don
      spark:spark.eventLog.dir: gs://<bucketname>/spark-job-history/events
      spark:spark.executor.cores: '8'
      spark:spark.executor.instances: '2'
      spark:spark.executor.memory: 8379m
      spark:spark.executorEnv.OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS: '1'
      spark:spark.history.fs.logDirectory: gs://<bucketname>/spark-job-history
      spark:spark.scheduler.mode: FAIR
      spark:spark.sql.cbo.enabled: 'true'
```

***WorkAround***
On setting `spark.eventLog.enabled false` , in spark-submit command , the job works fine. But we will not have access to spark history server to analyse logs later.

**ERROR:**

````
java.io.IOException: Error accessing gs://<bucketname>/spark-job-history/events
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageImpl.getObject(GoogleCloudStorageImpl.java:1959)
    
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.getFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1083)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.getFileStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1079)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.start(EventLoggingListener.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:523)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2520)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:930)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
    
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)

    ... 25 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:456)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:323)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:271)
    sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:451)```
````

Comment: Do you use any initialization actions when creating a cluster?

Comment: Yes, we do use it and it is to copy few stuff from bucket and run some commands.

Comment: Will Spark job work with `spark.eventLog.enabled=true` property if you will not use any initialization actions and Datarproc-provided (not custom) image to create a cluster?

Comment: Can you run `gsutil ls gs://<bucketname>/spark-job-history/events` and `gsutil cp <sample-file> gs://<bucketname>/spark-job-history/events/` in the master node to see if the service account has access to the bucket?

Comment: Yes it has access to bucket, since our init script is able to download few files from same bucket.

Comment: Did you enable Kerberos in the cluster?

Comment: Also make sure it has write access to the bucket.

Comment: @UsmanAzhar Why have you disabled conscrypt? What happens if you enable it?

Comment: is it fixed for you?